# Prettier extension in VScode keeps breaking lines when formatting

Tags: vscode-extensions, prettier

when I format with prettier extension my code looks like this

```
app.post(
    "/products",
    wrapAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
        const newProduct = new Product(req.body);
        await newProduct.save();
        res.redirect(`/products/${newProduct._id}`);
    })
);
```

I want my code to look like this

```
app.post("/products", wrapAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
        const newProduct = new Product(req.body);
        await newProduct.save();
        res.redirect(`/products/${newProduct._id}`);
    })
);
```

Is there anyway stop this from happening?